# Open url in new tab using javascript without click an anchor

Tags: javascript

i read a lot of solutions but all of them are clicking a url, and it works, but my client ask me to do is users opens his website, it automatically open a new tab with some special offers , so my question, is there any way to open a new tab without any user intervention? , maybe a jquery plugin?, i know the tabs rely on the web browser, but it have to be a way, a lot of web pages does it,but how?

Greetings

Comment: i have hear of pop-ups, pop-unders, but never "pop-new-tab". this is a browser setting you are dealing with, and you can't change that from the script perspective (unless you have a plugin to give you that leverage). some browsers open to a new tab by default, some open in new windows.

Comment: your client came from the 90s i suppose - you ought to tell him that today this is not a good idea btw

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying the configuration of browser, the answer is **no**, only [trusted event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events) can open a new window (or tab)

You may ask if your client could change their browser's configuration to allow a popup window from an untrusted javascript program.

Answer (score 0):

Write script in your page to open new page:

```
    <script>
      window.open("specialOffers.aspx");
    </script>
```

and in the "specialOffers.aspx" page in the  tag write:

```
    <base target="_blank"/>
```